# DNS - Load Balancer - SINGLE Apache Server - Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, dns, load-balancing, rackspace

This is my configuration, I have bought a domain in godaddy.com. Linked my Load Balancer[in Rackspace] IP in domain setting. Behind the Load Balancer, there is one active server which responds all request.

Now I when I change the Load Balancer IP in godaddy to the server IP which has that SINGLE Apache and tomcat behind that apache. But now the server stops serving the request after 30 minutes. Even I could not access with my server IP address.[Godaddy have changed the IP to new server, I have checked through ping also for the first 15 minutes it responds through the Load Balancer after that godaddy changes the IP to the Server. The server will work for next 15 minutes and thats it.]

I have changed my server from azure and AWS and checked the same thing in both, but both had the same problem.

Do I need to learn any resource for this? 
Does the apache which is in my server can't handle 200 request for 2 minutes?
Does the problem is related to Rackspace Load Balancer?

Please shed some light on this. Thanks

Comment: not sure I understand: you mean that the whole problem is that the IP of your server is changing over time? It is not possible (at least easily and reliably) to create DNS records on changing IP. You have to get a server with a fix IP address. For example on AWS you can attach an elastic IP to your EC2 instance, and this IP will remain attached to your instance as long as you want.

Comment: No, we are not using dynamic IP, the server IP is static. But we are changing the load balancer IP to server static IP in godaddy dns settings.